# Xcode WDL-OL VST3 Semantic Issue; Use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

Im trying to get Xcode to compile VST3 plugin. Using WDL-OL.
Fresh install of MacOS Sierra.
Using this guide for setup: http://martin-finke.de/blog/articles/audio-plugins-002-setting-up-wdl-ol/
Also using XcodeLegacy to install all libs/sdk's.
App,VST2 and AU compile/work. VST3 and AAX do not.

```
wdl-ol/VST3_SDK/public.sdk/source/common/memorystream.cpp:41:1: 
Use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr'
```

**memorystream.cpp**

```
IMPLEMENT_FUNKNOWN_METHODS (MemoryStream, IBStream, IBStream::iid)
static const TSize kMemGrowAmount = 4096;
```

I've tried all 3 compilers, different base sdk's.
When C++ Language Dialect is set to C++11 or GNU++11 i get a different Semantic Issue error:

```
wdl-ol/WDL/IPlug/IGraphicsMac.mm:279:21: Non-constant-expression cannot 
be narrowed from type 'int' to 'CGFloat' (aka 'double') in initializer list
```

**IGraphicsMac.mm**

```
NSSize size = { w, h };
[(IGRAPHICS_COCOA*) mGraphicsCocoa setFrameSize: size ];
```

### Different environments tried'

> Xcode8.1 - MacOS Siera10.12.11 (fresh-install!)
>
> Xcode6, 6.1, 7, 7.2.1, 7.3.1 - Yosemite10.10.5 (old setup)

Comment: I don't think WDL-OL can be used with C++11 (at least I've never got it working). Hopefully someone can prove me wrong here though!